# Sporadic FTP connection timeouts when establishing a Control Connection with a Cloud-hosted FTP server

Tags: ftp, pureftpd

Our team has to host and maintain a publicly-visible FTP server for the needs of our application. It's currently hosted on a Google Compute Engine VM, and the FTP server software in use is [Pure-FTPd](https://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/). Also, we tried [FileMage](https://www.filemage.io/).

When accessing the server through any mainstream FTP client, like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), by its public address, the server seems to work perfectly fine, being capable of ingesting/exporting large amounts of data at once without any issues.

**The problem**

In our pipeline, we have a spot where a big number of files are programmatically downloaded from this server, processed, and then re-exported to an adjacent directory. By the big number, I mean ~2000-8000 files ~20MB in size each going back and forth.

The programmatic FTP client we use is [Apache FTPCLient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

This operation seems to complete fine in most cases but will always produce an enormous amount of "Connection timeout" errors, in a spot where the client tries to establish an FTP Control Connection on port 21. Basically, the only reason all files end up transferred is us having a very generous retry mechanism in place. The timeout we use for establishing a control connection is 60 seconds which seems to be higher than what, for example, FileZilla uses.

---

What could be the culprit of these connection errors? It does not seem to be a hardware issue. Neither downgrading the number of client machines nor using a "load-balanced" FTP server with 10 backend machines in work seemed to help us get rid of these errors.

We pretty much achieved a state where the server is only accessed by two threads simultaneously, with as much connection re-usage as possible, and still, the sporadic "Connection timeout" errors are there. Has anyone run into the same problem?